# Trying to fit html content in single pdf page in Mpdf

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I am trying to fit a div which consists of internal divs and tables in one page pdf. Is there anyway to resize the div elements or scale or zoom so that it can fit inside one page. I have tried adding page-break-inside:avoid in div but it's not working.

Comment: what you try ? Need more information ?

Comment: While creating pdf html content is large so it is taking 2 pages. I need to display it in single pdf page. Is there anyway of scaling the content so it can fit in single page.

Comment: Show us your pdf generating code.